# Run command line EXE on Azure, supplying a path to an Azure Blob

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I have an Azure web app that stores documents in Azure blob "container X".

Now, we want to run a "job" to generate specialized reports for these documents.

This includes running an EXE file that takes a document path as argument, letting it generate a report on the file system, and uploading this to Azure blob "container Y".

Like: `generate-report.exe document.doc` generates `report.txt`.

How can this be done? Do we need to download the blob to the web app, or is it possible to somehow refer to a blob as we refer to a physical disk file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot refer to a blob as a local file object, since blob storage does not implement any type of file I/O abstraction layer. Yes, you can use File Storage service, which implements SMB on top of blob storage, but this is different than working with individual blobs.

If your app is built to deal just with file objects, you'd need to copy it from blob storage to local disk first, then upload the results from local disk to blob storage.

If you're just building your app, you can directly access blob content via the REST API (or one of the various language-specific SDK's that wrap the API).

Answer (score 0):

Reading file from the blob can be done in form of stream that can later be used to create the text file inside the web app also.
You can also create web jobs under web app to accomplish this task in backend.

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/documentation/articles/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs/